# Анимация во время загрузки

Tags: php, html, css

Как я понял на PHP реализовать прогресс загрузки файла (в процентах) если и возможно то очень сложно. Так вот хотелось бы узнать, а как хотя бы реализовать что бы во время загрузки появлялась анимация (gif), ну а после загрузки исчезала. Вот простейшая реализация загрузки файлов на сервер. Как сюда прикрутить анимацию.

```
<?
$path = 'upl/'; // директория для загрузки
$ext = array_pop(explode('.',$_FILES['userfile']['name'])); // расширение
$new_name = time().'.'.$ext; // новое имя с расширением
$full_path = $path.$new_name; // полный путь с новым именем и расширением

if($_FILES['userfile']['error'] == 0){
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $full_path)){
    // Если файл успешно загружен, то вносим в БД (надеюсь, что вы знаете как)
    // Можно сохранить $full_path (полный путь) или просто имя файла - $new_name
  }
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

На самом деле для загрузки файлов вполне себе работает метод ajaxSubmit из плагина jQuery Form, у которого есть callback после удачного завершения.
Либо использовать PHP extension для аплоада (uploadprogress, PHP >= 5.2)

Т.е. в случае с jQuery будет так:

```
$('#form_id').submit(function() {
    $('#loading').show(); // Показываем анимацию загрузки
    $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        success: function() {
            $('#loading').hide(); // Скрываем анимацию загрузки
        }
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

Код будет примерно такой:

```
<?php
if (count($_FILES['userfile'])) {
    $path = 'upl/'; // директория для загрузки
    $ext = array_pop(explode('.',$_FILES['userfile']['name'])); // расширение
    $new_name = time().'.'.$ext; // новое имя с расширением
    $full_path = $path.$new_name; // полный путь с новым именем и расширением

    if($_FILES['userfile']['error'] == 0){
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $full_path)){
            // Если файл успешно загружен, то вносим в БД (надеюсь, что вы знаете как)
            // Можно сохранить $full_path (полный путь) или просто имя файла - $new_name
        }
    }   
}
?>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form_id').submit(function() {
        $('#loading').show(); // Показываем анимацию загрузки
        $(this).ajaxSubmit({
            success: function() {
                $('#loading').hide(); // Скрываем анимацию загрузки
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
<img src="loading.gif" id="loading" alt="" style="display: none;" />
<form id="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
    <input type="file" name="userfile" />
    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload file" />
</form>
```

Comment: То есть как я понял `#form_id` это айдишник формы загрузки, а `div` с анимацией имеет айдишник `#loading`. И по умолчанию у `#loading` стоит css свойство display:none. Поправьте если я не прав !!! Потому что таким образом это не работает.

Comment: Да, всё именно так..

Comment: Странно но у меня ни чего не происходит, вроде и плагин подключил, и все ровно не хочет.

Comment: Может я его не туда ставлю, может внутрь формы надо или как ?

Comment: Ну я же не вижу ваш код. Выложите его куда-нить типа pastebin.com и дайте ссылку.

Comment: Код приведен в вопросе.Например так :

    `Вышеизложенный код (из вопроса)`
     <form>
         <input type="file" />
         <img src="loading.gif" id="loading" />
         <input type="submit" />
     </form>
Ну вот примерно так, у меня файлы загружаются, но нет анимации. В форме много полей, и анимация должна появляется только если файл выбран и загружается, если же файл не загружается то анимашки не должно быть. Атрибуты в форме не пишу, я думаю суть я передал.

    Главный вопрос: куда вставить тот код который вы мне написали

Comment: Обновил свой ответ.